# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, dns, browser, ipconfig, google-public-dns

I thoroughly examined [all similar questions](https://superuser.com/search?q=DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN%20is%3Aqueston), but none of the above recommendations did help me. I am still getting the error on this concrete PC with Windows 10 Creators Update, while all other devices (Win8, Android) are going fine.

The only commands that help me are (should be executed in pair in that particular order, otherwise useless):

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
```

The problem is they help only **temporarily**, after a while (5-10-20 min) all is reverted back and I cannot connect to any destination.
Any suggestions how to fix this?

**P.S.** It happens **both** with Google Public DNS and DNS of my ISP, and it happens **both** in Chromium and Edge, and it happens **both** with enabled and disabled firewall.

Comment: The error message mentioned in the title is specific do Chrome. `ipconfig /flushdns` effects are local to your PC. While `ipconfig /registerdns` effects are not, they have no direct relation to DNS resolution. So your OS has some subtle error. Did you reset the WinSock catalog yet?

Comment: Not yet. I did `netsh winsock reset` but not `catalog`. Just did it, let's see how it's going on.

Comment: @DanielB, no resetting catalog didn't help ((

Comment: Well even though it sucks I’d recommend reinstalling. Please note that the “Reset” feature may not be enough, you’ll have to create a bootable installation medium.